# When MongoDB collection has no data, perform operation on $project data

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to perform the operation after inserting data to `$projection` like following,

```
db.test.aggregate([ { $project:{ data: [my data] } } ]);
```

the `test` collection is empty and I don't want to insert any records to the collection and want to perform the operation on projected data like paginating, sorting, etc.

for the solution I found a way, for that, I can simply insert one record and in aggregate, I use $project to insert data and it works.

I just want to know is there any why if the collection is empty can I use $project and my data to perform an operation on it?

Thank You

Comment: Yes If you are better in mongodb aggregation rather than the javascript, you can do. Just use `{ $limit: 1 }` before `$project` stage and `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` after it. And also it will take max time to make operations on the large data set.

Comment: @Ashh that is what I did, I've used `$limit` but it requires a single document in the collection, and my question is to perform without andy document in the collection.

Comment: Then I think you must keep at least one document in the collection.